# Error when splicing

Tags: python

In my program I am asking the name of a person. Then I splice the strings to only have their initials.

```
# Ask for names
first=input('Please enter your first name: ')
middle=input('Please enter your middle name: ')
last=input('Please enter your last name: ')
# Splice
first[1]
middle[1]
last[1]
```

The Program gives an error when splicing the middle name is a person left it blank. Can someone help me solve the error?

Comment: Are you sure that you want `first[1]` but not `first[0]`?

Comment: `middle = middle[1] if len(middle) > 0 else "" `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a string is empty, it will have no characters so accessing any index raises errors. You need to test if the string is empty before taking an index. `if middle` is the easiest way to test as that evaluates as `False` if the string is empty.

```
if middle:
    middle[0]
```

Note that `[1]` will take the second element, as indexing starts at 0, not 1. So you want `[0]`. Also, this is indexing, not slicing. Slicing is when you take a series of values from the string, indexing is when you access a single character.

Comment: This isn't my whole program, just the part that gave me errors.

Comment: @Duece Ah I see, apologies then. I removed the unnecessary part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you are not sure if the user may input a blank string or a valid name then best way is to use an `if - else` construct, or if you want to do it more pythonically then you may try:

```
>>> middle = "anmol"
>>> middle[1:2]
>>> "n"
>>> middle = ""
>>> middle[1:2]
>>> "" # No error here.
```